# PsExec return data type

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, psexec

PsExec seems to be returning different types from what would be expected from running the command locally. I'm trying to run this command remotely `Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem` using this

```
$computerSystem = &$workingDirectory/psexec.exe \\10.44.20.20 powershell.exe "Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem"
```

The usual return type for `Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem` returns a CimInstance and members can be accessed like this `$computerSystem.Name`.

However, when using psexec it returns a strangely formatted Object Array. When looking at the variable whilst debugging it appears to have the same members as the CimInstance but they can't be accessed due to the object array type.

Is there a way to cast this to a CimInstance or get psexec to access its members or to make psexec return the expected type?

Comment: Why are you using `psexec` instead of PowerShell remoting (`invoke-command`) or passing `-computername` to `get-ciminstance`?

Comment: I was not aware of the -ComputerName parameter for Get-CimInstance. This solves the issue I was having, thank you. Any idea why PsExec behaves this way?

Comment: `psexec` is not PowerShell and cannot return objects. It just outputs strings like any other command, which PowerShell then parses. Like @alroc said, you want to use the actual remoting features of the commands in question. (The `ps` in `PsExec` doesn't stand for PowerShell -- [that prefix was adopted because the standard Unix command for listing processes is `ps`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx).)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-ComputerName` parameter for `Get-CimInstance` instead of `psexec`. This will return objects which are usable by Powershell, instead of string data.